# UITableView is not updating once the row is deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 and I have two UITableViews where I set data fetched from a core-data module entity called UserIncome. As these data will be populated in two UItableViews in a single UIViewController (filtering based on a String value in the ViewWillAppear delegate method),once a row is been deleted in one UITableView, its array automatically gets updated by the other tableView's objects too. But once I click the back button and come back to the same UIViewController all seems fine. My requirement is to update the UItableView once a row is been deleted so as the core data module. The code as bellow. What am I missing here?

```
 import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyIncomesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var recurringIncomeTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var otherIncomeTableView: UITableView!
    //var myIncomeType : String?

    var stores = [UserIncome] ()
    var other = [UserIncome] ()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var rowTbl : Int!
    var rowTbl2 : Int!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

}
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        stores.removeAll()
        other.removeAll()

        let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "UserIncome")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false



        do {

            let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [UserIncome]

            print("Results from the fetch request are : ", request)

            // check data existance
            if results.count>0 {
                print("results are :", results.count)

                for resultGot in results {

                    //lets check if the data is available and whether the loop is working by printing out the "name"
                    if let incName = resultGot.incomeName {
                        print("expence name is :", incName)

                        //set the value to the global variable as to filter the arrays 
                        let myIncomeType = resultGot.incomeType

                        if myIncomeType == "Recurring Income"{

                          stores += [resultGot]
                          print("my recurring income array is : \(stores)")
                        }else if myIncomeType == "Other Income"{

                          other += [resultGot]
                          print("my other income array is : \(other)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.recurringIncomeTableView.reloadData()
                self.otherIncomeTableView.reloadData()

            }

        }catch{


            print("No Data to load")
        }


    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView.tag == 1 {
        let cell: RecuringIncomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recurringIncomeCell") as! RecuringIncomeTableViewCell

        let store = stores [indexPath.row]

        cell.incomeNameLabel.text = store.incomeName
        cell.amountLabel.text = store.amount


        return cell

        }
        else {
            let cell: OtherIncomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherIncomeCell") as! OtherIncomeTableViewCell

            let otherIncomes = other [indexPath.row]

            cell.incomeNameLabel.text = otherIncomes.incomeName
            cell.amountLabel.text = otherIncomes.amount


            return cell

        }
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "editStore", sender: nil)
        if tableView.tag == 1 {
           rowTbl = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            print("current row in tbl 1 is : ",rowTbl)

        }else {

          rowTbl2 = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            print("current row in tbl 2 is : ",rowTbl2)
        }

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editRecurringIncome"{

            let v = segue.destination as! AddIncomeViewController
            let indexPath = self.recurringIncomeTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let row = indexPath?.row
            v.store = stores[row!]

        }else if segue.identifier == "editOtherIncome" {
            let t = segue.destination as! AddIncomeViewController
            let indexPath = self.otherIncomeTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let row = indexPath?.row
            t.store = other [row!]

        }
    }

//    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        print("delete delegate being activated")
        return true
    }

    //For remove row from tableview & object from array.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                let task = stores [indexPath.row]
                context.delete(task)
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()


                do {
                    stores = try context.fetch(UserIncome.fetchRequest())
                    print("Stores deleted from indexPath",stores)
                }catch{
                    print("fail")
                }


               recurringIncomeTableView.reloadData()

            }

            self.recurringIncomeTableView.reloadData()

        } else if tableView.tag == 2 {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                let task = other[indexPath.row]
                print("task on otherTblView is : ",task)
                context.delete(task)
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
                otherIncomeTableView.reloadData()

                do {
                    other = try context.fetch(UserIncome.fetchRequest())
                    print("Stores deleted from indexPath",other)
                }catch{
                    print("fail")
                }

        }


            self.otherIncomeTableView.reloadData()
        }
        tableView.reloadData()


    }


}
```

Comment: post tableview code too where you write content in it...

Comment: It is there Sir

Comment: Try to call viewDidAppear() not tableView.reloadData() inside func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: @danu : try one thing... call second reload after 1 second using nstimer and see how it goes...

Comment: what about your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method?

Comment: Seems thats not working either

Comment: I didn't upload the unnecessary code since its make this hard to read. However even in the numberOfRowsInSection method the count gets updated in the wrong manner the fact once a row is being deleted its array automatically gets updated by the other one's objects (other tableViews objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delete task like this way

```
let task = stores [indexPath.row]
context.delete(task)
stores.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) // i think you forget this line
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

try this,hope it will help you

Comment: I did that too but seems still its the same. For instance if I delete a row in my first tableView, the values of the other tableView get populate to that tableView automatically. Would much appreciate if u could help me with this small matter

Answer (score 0):

A core data object doesn't really contain any information.  It has a pointer to a context and an ID, so when you ask it for information it goes to the store to ask.  If the object is deleted from the context then the manage object that you have stored in your array will no longer work and will crash.  This is why you should never retain `NSManagedObjects`.  Either

a) Copy the values from core data into an a different object. When you want to delete an object you have to delete it from both the store and the copy that you are retaining.  If new objects are inserted, or they are deleted from some other source outside of you viewController it will not update (but also no crash).

b) Use a `NSFetchedResultsController` and update the results when the values change. This will give a delegate to tell you when changes happen.  So all you have to do it delete the object from the store and then the fetchedResultsController will tell you when to remove it.